# Simple question on gradient of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative

Let A be an $m \times n $ matrix where $m \gt n$, $x \in \Bbb R^n, b\in \Bbb R^m$. Denote $|| \cdot || $ as $L^2$-norm

let $f(x)=||Ax-b||^2_2$

then $\nabla f(x)=A^TAx-A^Tb$

I have trouble in understanding why it is the case

Thank you!

Comment: Does it help if I point out that for vectors $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ we have that $||y||_2^2 = y^{T}\cdot y$?

Comment: Then I would have $\nabla f(x)=\nabla (Ax-b)^T \cdot (Ax-b) + (Ax-b)^T \cdot \nabla (Ax-b)=A^T \cdot (Ax-b) +(Ax-b)^T \cdot A=???$
Seems I have done something wrong, could you help me to find it?

Comment: I was thinking of more in the direction $f(x)=x^TA^TAx - b^TAx-x^TA^Tb+b^Tb.$ What then is $f(x+h)-f(x)$?

Comment: So what I left is $h^TA^TAx+x^TA^TAh+h^TA^TAh-b^TAh-h^TA^Tb$, how can I relate this to $\nabla f(x)$

Comment: Actually, is it meant to be $\nabla f(x) = 2(A^TAx -A^Tb)$?

Comment: I'm not sure, actually I was told to minimize $f(x)$ and the solution just says $\nabla f(x)=A^TAx-A^Tb=0$. Maybe you're right that the factor of 2 is just eliminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to finish what I was talking about in the comments, notice that $x^TA^TAh$ and $b^TAh$ are real numbers and are so equal to their transpose. This gives us $$f(x+h)-f(x) = 2(h^T(A^TAx -A^Tb)) + h^TA^TAh.$$ From this and rearranging we can conclude that $$\frac{||f(x+h)-f(x) - 2(h^T(A^TAx -A^Tb))||_2}{||h||_2}\to 0 $$ as $h\to 0$. Hence $\nabla f=2(A^TAx -A^Tb)$.

Alternatively, $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(Ax-b) = Ae_i$. Therefore by the chain rule, $$\frac{\partial d}{dx_i}(f) = (\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} (Ax-b))^T(Ax-b) + (Ax-b)^T(\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(Ax-b)) = 2e_i^T(A^TAx-A^Tb). $$ Using similar reasoning to the above. Hence $\nabla f=2(A^TAx -A^Tb)$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the multivariable chain rule.  Note that $f(x) = g(h(x))$ where $h(x) = Ax - b$ and $g(y) = \| y \|_2^2$.
From the chain rule,
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= g'(h(x)) h'(x) \\
&= 2(Ax - b)^TA .
\end{align}
It follows that
$$
\nabla f(x) = f'(x)^T = 2 A^T(Ax - b).
$$

In the above derivation, we used the fact that $h'(x) = A$ (here we are using the standard formula for the derivative of a linear transformation)
and we also used the fact that $g'(y) = 2y^T$, which is easy to show.